# How can I build backend services for my mobile app

Tags: flutter, cloud, backend, cross-platform, infrastructure

I want to learn to build a simple log-in page using Flutter with its backend services. Is this infrastructure good? Are there any suggestions?

- The profile picture of the user must be stored on a cloud storage
- To check the identity of the user and to retrieve the profile picture
  I guess a databank should do the work.
- The user should see when was the last time he/she logged in. How can I do it?

I want to use Firebase to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I understood that you want to develop a simple login app with authentication using Firebase.
**Firebase console services** enable you to authenticate and firebase storage can be used to store and retrieve the login data. **You can implement something like storing the date-time at every login or logout and save it in db. Update it if the login user entry exists previously otherwise add new entry to the table.**

You can visit below link to read about how to implement firebase storage. It will provide you database as well as cloud storage service. So nothing other than that is required.

[Pub dev for firebase storage](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
But when do I need server-side languages like PHP, js, node js, etc.?

Comment: @BisherA-K You will need a scripting language like node js or php when you are developing separate api's . For example if i use a database which cannot be directly used in flutter i would need to make an api for it. That api will be developed in some scripting language that will act as mediator between the db and your flutter application.

Comment: It would be like having dart code and inside of it there will code of another language, right? how is that possible?

Comment: No dart code will only request the API . The API code which is the scripting language here will be separate. There are methods to request and response for them. The code will not be written inside dart project and will be separate project of PHP itself. It is generally referred as backend.